# Xcode autolayout issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

Here is a screenshot of whats happening: [image]

No matter what constraints I use on the 8 colors on the right hand side, I either get ambiguous layout or no images at all, or images that appear but are cut off the screen or deformed. Same thing happens with the other ones on the left and middle. Maybe im going about this all wrong but hopefully there is a simple solution.

[image]

Here is the main issue. I added 1 constraint to each image (right side), this is where i get the ambiguous layout error, and the deformed image.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is no code yet

Comment: Show us the view structure in that area and the current constraints.

Comment: That UI is crying out to be a uicollectionview. Don't even attempt to lay it out yourself. Just use a collection view.

Comment: Ill try that, do the images (colors, pieces) go into the cells? And do I use 1 cells for every item?